# Meteor Router + PhantomJS

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

My Meteor application uses Meteor router for navigation and Spiderable plugin to get pages indexed by search engines. Spiderable calls phantomjs to get page content. This approach works ok for most pages except home page.

```
   '/': ->
    'home'
  '/otherurl': ->
    'otherpage'
```

I did some debugging and found that the callback of page.evaluate in spiderable.js always returns false in the case when home page was requested

```
...  
setInterval(function() {
  var ready = page.evaluate(function () {
    if (typeof Meteor !== 'undefined' && typeof(Meteor.status) !== 'undefined' && Meteor.status().connected) {
      Meteor.flush();
      return Meteor._LivedataConnection._allSubscriptionsReady();
    }
    return false;
  });
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the code of `home` function of router.

Comment: Finally i found that the following code caused the problem:
`Meteor.autosubscribe ->
       Meteor.subscribe 'items',Session.get('item_id')`
Since at start Session is empty _allSubscriptionsReady() returned false all time and that caused phantomjs to hang up.

Comment: Did you fix this? If so, please post an answer below :) There are way too many questions in the [meteor] tag that has answers existing in the comments section only.